# Cannot free space from deleted files (available space is 0 bit)

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage

I was notified that my disk is almost full. So, I deleted files from my trash but the space  was not freed - the available space is 0 bit. I caused that I am not able to boot. Also, I tried to use a live Ubuntu USB stick and remove some more files using `rm -r` but available space is 0 bit again. How can I make some space?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You're rather light on specifics.   If this is a desktop install; the [recommended minimum disk size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) has been 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 thus include 18.04. If you've allocated less than that; freeing space is less the cure than increase disk size. For server installs it's more complex (depends on packages or *how system is used).  Either way we can't suggest much as we know little. You can use `du` to view disk usage to find where it's being used (be it installed apps; log files that need maintenance etc) etc

Answer (score 4):

0 bytes remaining is not *almost full*, it's *totally full*. This condition can cause so many widespread problems that it's generally fatal.  Because completely running out of space can cause so many different problems, it may be extremely difficult to find and fix them all.

It's recommended that you reinstall the OS if this happens.

It's obviously very inconvenient to have to reinstall so take great care to make sure you don't let this happen again.  Try to determine how/why this happened so that you do not repeat the same problems on the new installation.

The minimum recommended space for Ubuntu Desktop is 25 GB.  It would be wise to allocate more space if you can afford it.